# I want to deploy a Django app on Heroku, but I got error

Tags: python, django, git, github, heroku

## I want to deploy a Django app on Heroku.

The development environment is wsl (debian), python3.9.0, and the virtual environment is "venv".

I referred here:
https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/ja/heroku/

It was completed before this code:
`git push heroku master`

Run `git push heroku master`, 
then I got the following error:

```
(env) me@Ver:~/docker_heroku/djangogirls210307$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 78, done.
Counting objects: 100% (78/78), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (78/78), 25.08 KiB | 885.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 78 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: ad15f239126a3588a2ab6585b0ae52bfa25d9b7e
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version ad15f239126a3588a2ab6585b0ae52bfa25d9b7e
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to django-210307.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/django-210307.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/django-210307.git'
```

I've run `heroku create`, 
"djangogirls210307" has been created on heroku.

The output below is the information obtained with `heroku info --app diangogirls210307`

```
=== djangogirls210307
Auto Cert Mgmt: false
Dynos:          
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/djangogirls210307.git
Owner:          mailme@gmail.com
Region:         us
Repo Size:      0 B
Slug Size:      0 B
Stack:          heroku-20
Web URL:        https://djangogirls210307.herokuapp.com/
```

I also named the work directory "djangogirls210307" and worked with the following structure in it.

```
djangogirls210307/
|
|- env  // by "venv", not "virtualenv""pipenv"
|-mysite // name of project
 |-__init__.py
 |-asgi.py
 |-local_settings.py
 |-urls.py
 |-settings.py
 |-wsgi.py
|-.gitignore
|-manage.py
|-Procfile
|-requirements.txt
|-runtime.txt
```

In the error,'django-210307.git' is displayed, but it is probably the remote repository created during practice today.

### So, I would like to ask the following questions. Thank you for your cooperation.

1. I want to know the procedure until the deployment is completed successfully.
2. I want to know if it can be solved by changing the push destination.
   However, I don't understand why the push destination was fixed with the `git push heroku master` command.
3. I want to know how to change and specify the push destination.
4. Please let me know if you don't mind if you use the wrong word in the question.

Comment: p.s. I logged in Heroku, via `heroku login --interactive`, because I have no web browser in WSL/Debian, `heroku login` command will not log in.

Answer (score 0):

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

Set a buildpack manually:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Comment: Thanks, Tin.

Before
 `git push heroku master`, 

I shoud command it 
`heroku buildpachs...`, 
right?